# Меню при наведении на ссылку

Tags: jquery

Есть следующий код.

Нужно, чтобы при наведении или при нажатии на

`<li class="dropbox-menu"><a href="">Меню при наведении</a></li>`

отображался блок с классом `dropbox`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.dropbox-menu').hover(function() {
    $('.dropbox').removeClass('uk-hidden');
  });

  $('.dropbox-menu').click(function() {
    $('.dropbox').toggleClass('uk-hidden');
    return false;
  });

});
```

```css
header {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  height: 50px;
  background: #F0F0F0;
}

header .navbar li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 15%;
  list-style: none;
}

.header {
  position: relative;
}

.dropbox {
  position: absolute;
  right: 20px;
  top: 50px;
  width: 256px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  border-top: 1px solid #D0D0D0;
  padding: 0 24px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 16px 32px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08), 0px 2px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16);
  box-shadow: 0px 16px 32px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08), 0px 2px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16);
  border-bottom-right-radius: 8px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 8px;
}

.dropbox li {
  list-style: none;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.uk-hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
  <div class="header">
    <ul class="navbar">
      <li><a href="">Пункт 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Пункт 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Пункт 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Пункт 4</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Пункт 5</a></li>
      <li class="dropbox-menu"><a href="">Меню при наведении</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div class="dropbox uk-hidden">
      <ul class="uk-margin-remove uk-padding-remove">
        <li><a href="">Пункт 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Пункт 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Пункт 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Пункт 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Пункт 5</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Пункт 6</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Пункт 7</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Но возникает проблема, что меню не пропадает если уводим мышь с выпадашки + если нажимаем на кнопку и отводим мышь, то меню снова появляется

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.dropbox-menu').hover(function() {
  $('.dropbox').removeClass('uk-hidden');
});
```

Вы используете removeClass() вместо toggleClass(), вследствие чего наблюдалась ваша проблема. Немного отрефакторил вашу функцию - и все получилось:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  const dropboxToggle = function() { // задаем функцию появления и исчезновения элемента
    $('.dropbox').toggleClass('uk-hidden');
         return false;
  }

  $('.dropbox-menu').click(dropboxToggle).hover(dropboxToggle); // привязываем к событиям click() и hover()
});
```

Рабочий образец: https://jsfiddle.net/s8agcb0z/

Comment: Так делал. Получается, если уводим мышь с класса ".dropbox-menu", то меню сразу исчезает и пользователь не сможет выбрать пункт, только посмотреть.

Comment: Понял вас, тогда подумаю еще

Comment: setTimeout(function(){
   $('.dropbox').addClass('uk-hidden');
  },1000); щас пробую с этой функцией, но при наведении на блок самого меню, он исчезает все равно)

Comment: попробуйте этот вариант, это то, что нужно?
https://jsfiddle.net/s8agcb0z/1/

Comment: Да, только есть небольшая проблема: если наводим мышкой на кнопку, затем сразу нажимаем на нее и уводим мышь, то список не закрывается